# Creating tables using plotly

Tags: python-2.7, plotly, spyder

I am using plotly offline to create a table.But the output is displayed as a single row,not as shown in the output format given in the following link(i.e not as a table)

> https://plot.ly/python/table/#changing-row-and-column-size(“Changing Row and column size”)

Here is the code,

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
#plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
values = [[['geneNames', 'uniprotIDs', 'ec-code', 'subcellularLocation', 'tissueSpecificity',
            'proteinName', 'subunit', 'species']], [[' G6PC', ' P35575', ' 3.1.3.9',
            '  Endoplasmic reticulum membrane', 'No Data', ' Glucose-6-phosphatase alpha',
            'No Data', ' Homo sapiens']]]
trace0 = go.Table(
  type = 'table',
  columnorder = [1,2],
  columnwidth = [80,400],
  header = dict(
    values = [['<b>PARAMETERS</b>'],
                  ['<b>VALUES</b>']],
    line = dict(color = '#506784'),
    fill = dict(color = '#119DFF'),
    align = ['left','center'],
    font = dict(color = 'white', size = 12),
    height = 40
  ),
  cells = dict(
    values = values,
    line = dict(color = '#506784'),
    fill = dict(color = ['#25FEFD', 'white']),
    align = ['left', 'center'],
    font = dict(color = '#506784', size = 12),
    height = 30
    ))

data = [trace0]
plot(data)
```

I would like to ask for some help

EDIT:
 Would it be possible to save the table in png/txt format?I tried replacing 'uniprot.html' with 'uniprot.png'. But the file gets saved as uniprot.png.html.

Comment: The output table opens as a html file.Instead of manually using the save icon in order to save the file,I wish to save it programmatically. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Try `plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='uniprot.html', auto_open=False)`

Comment: Would it be possible to save the table in png/txt format?I tried replacing 'uniprot.html' with 'uniprot.png'. But the file gets saved as uniprot.png.html.

Comment: Please ask only question at once, otherwise it is difficult for other users to find answers.

Comment: Thanks.I have added the question to the initial post

Answer (score 2):

Looks like as if the document and the current version of Plotly are out of sync. Try using a simple of list of two lists (column 1 and column 2).

```
values = [['geneNames', 'uniprotIDs', 'ec-code', 'subcellularLocation', 'tissueSpecificity', 'proteinName', 'subunit', 'species'], 
          [' G6PC', ' P35575', ' 3.1.3.9', '  Endoplasmic reticulum membrane', 'No Data', ' Glucose-6-phosphatase alpha', 'No Data', ' Homo sapiens']
         ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about saving (figures) as PNG, check out [orca](https://github.com/plotly/orca).  This is the graphing engine which sits behind plotly.

To be honest, it's a little fiddly at first, but easy once you get going, and it provides PNG support!